# Where did dired-omit-toggle disappear in Emacs 23.2?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, dired

The challenge of upgrading from Emacs 21.2 to 23.2 continues... In my .emacs I have the very convenient:

```
(global-set-key (quote [f4]) (quote dired-omit-toggle))
```

It used to work since Emacs 18... but it no longer works in Emacs 23.2:

> Lisp error: (void-function
>   dired-omit-toggle)

Any idea how I can replace this functionality in Emacs 23.2?

[EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredExtra#Dired_X) says:

> To use this mode add the following to
>   your InitFile.
>
> ```
>   (add-hook 'dired-load-hook
>             (function (lambda () (load "dired-x"))))
> ```

and this is exactly what I have been having all these years. But Emacs 23.2 doesn't like this anymore. Any idea what could have replaced it in Emacs 23.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Emacs 22, you need to call `dired-omit-mode` instead of `dired-omit-toggle`. You still need to load `dired-x`. From `NEWS.22`:

> *** In Dired-x, Omitting files is now a minor mode, dired-omit-mode.
>
> The mode toggling command is bound to M-o.  A new command
> dired-mark-omitted, bound to * O, marks omitted files.  The variable
> dired-omit-files-p is obsoleted, use the mode toggling function
> instead.

Comment: Gilles, you are a life saver. It seems that the challenges I face stem from the fact that I didn't go through Emacs 22, so its NEWS file is not right at the Emacs 23 I am trying to make work for me. Anyway, your suggestion works. I will shortly post the code that replaces it.

Answer (score 0):

Since my upgrade from Emacs 21 to 23 is gradual, having to maintain the same .emacs for several systems, some of which use Emacs 21, and some use Emacs 23, I came up with the following code:

```
(GNUEmacs21
 (global-set-key (quote [f4]) (quote dired-omit-toggle))
)

(GNUEmacs22
 (global-set-key (quote [f4]) (quote dired-omit-mode))
)

(GNUEmacs23
 (global-set-key (quote [f4]) (quote dired-omit-mode))
)
```

GNUEmacs21, GNUEmacs22 and GNUEmacs23 are defined earlier in the .emacs file as:

```
(defmacro GNUEmacs23 (&rest body)
  (list 'if (string-match "GNU Emacs 23" (version))
        (cons 'progn body)))

(defmacro GNUEmacs22 (&rest body)
  (list 'if (string-match "GNU Emacs 22" (version))
        (cons 'progn body)))

(defmacro GNUEmacs21 (&rest body)
  (list 'if (string-match "GNU Emacs 21" (version))
        (cons 'progn body)))
```

Comment: I do not recommend going this route, because you have to figure out exactly what version of Emacs changed the feature. Most such incompatibilities are best resolved by testing the availability of a function or variable. Here, I would do something like `(eval-after-load "dired-x" '(if (not (fboundp 'dired-omit-toggle)) (defalias 'dired-omit-toggle 'dired-omit-mode)))`.